# Condition of the Brouwer fixed-point theorem

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, fixed-point-theorems

While I know it is true that:

> Every continuous function from a nonempty convex compact subset $K$ of an Euclidean space to $K$ itself has a fixed point. (Wikipedia)

I am not sure whether a continuous function whose domain is $[0,1]$ but with the range being $(0,1)$ can still apply the theorem and prove the existence of a fixed point. Also, for those functions whose domain takes $[0,+\infty)$, can I use a sufficiently large number $M$ to show $[0,M]\rightarrow [0, M]$ to prove the existence of a fixed point between $[0, M]$?

Comment: If $f$ is continuous $f: [0,1] \to [0,1]$, its range *cannot* be $(0,1)$.

Comment: The statement of Brouwer says nothing about range, and the exact range is unimportant - it can be any subset of $K.$

Comment: For the second question, does the function $f(x)=x+10^{-100}$ have a fixed point on $[0,+\infty)$?

Comment: @ChadK For your comment, $M+10^{-100}\not\in [0, M]$, so it is not the case of the question.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews So is it right: for every $x\in K$, the theorem only requires that $f(x)\in K$, where $f$ is a continuous function and $K$ is nonempty convex compact.

Comment: @YuzhenFeng:  The answer to the question is that such an $M$ does not have to exist.  If it exists, by resticting to $[0,M]$ you end up with a function $[0,M]\to[0,M]$ and you can forget where it originated from, and now you have a funtion on a space where Brouwer's theorem applies.

Comment: The continuous image of a compact set is compact.

Comment: Buy if the range would be say $\left[\frac{1}{4},\frac{3}{4}\right]$, there would still be a fixed point by Brouwer's fixed point theorem.

Comment: That is what the theorem says. What do you assume a function $K\to K$ is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. For each continuous function $f : [0,1] \to (0,1)$ there exists a point $x_0 \in (0,1)$ such that $f(x_0) = x_0$.

To see this, let $i : (0,1) \to [0,1]$ denote the inclusion function. Then $F = i \circ f : [0,1] \to [0,1]$ is continuous and has a fixed point $x_0 \in [0,1]$. We get $f(x_0) = F(x_0) = x_0$ and $x_0 = f(x_0) \in (0,1)$.

2. It is not clear which functions you consider on $[0,\infty)$.

If you are interested in functions $f : [0,\infty) \to [0,\infty)$, the answer is "no". As an example take $f(x) = x + 1$.

If you are interested in functions $f : [0,\infty) \to [0,M]$, the answer is "yes". Just take the restriction $f \mid_{[0,M]}$ which has a fixed point.